# Error occured during the simulation of videosensor node in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I had installed Omnet++ 4.4.2 and i have Castalia. Now i am getting a error in cCompoundModule. Please help me to find a solution for this error:

> Error in module (cCompundModule) SN (id=1) during network setup: Class **coordNode** not found - perhaps its code was not linked in or the class wasn't registered with `Register_Class()` or in the case of modules and channels with `Define_Module()` / `Define_Channel()`.

Comment: Image was not visible. Added error message to question.

Comment: In Castalia-3.2 there is no simplemodule nor compoundmodule named `coordNode`. Could you write which example do you try to run? Or how your network looks like (e.g. `*.ned` file(s) of your model as well as `omnetpp.ini`).

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah i had attached the images of my design and the .Ned file which i need to run.I need to run the omnetpp.ini file which comes under videosensornode.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWS3j.jpg)